# Import map server data: unable to edit data in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am trying to import the data from the below map server but have been having some trouble. I am trying to work with the **Census 2015 (EA) (0)** layer on the map server. I am able to use the option **View In: ArcMap**, which allows me to download a .lyr file that I can open in ArcMap. This file appears to have the map that I would like to use. However, I am unable to save this layer to a shapefile that I am able to edit. How do I go about getting a version of the map from the map server from a .lyr to a .shp that I can edit?

MapServer: https://www.integems-gis.solutions/server/rest/services/ms/sle_admin_boundaries/MapServer

Answer (score 3):

The service you are trying to access is a map service. The way i have always tried to think of it is a Map Service is a "graphic" or snap shot of the data that has been published on the server. Similar to a paper map, it is just for viewing and locked down so that you cannot extract or query the data.

If you want to extract and then edit the data, you need access to the "Feature Service". A Feature Service will give you access to the features with the published map.

When publishing a map to ArcGIS Online or Portal, a user can decide to include the Feature Service in the publishing process. It is an optional "tick-box" during the publishing steps.

So in order to try and get access to the information in the Map Service, you will need to contact the originator of the information to determine if there is a Feature Service you can use.